# Angular Controller Declaration

Tags: angularjs

I'm reading

https://www.syncfusion.com/resources/techportal/ebooks/angularjs

The third sample from the book on a basic usage fo the controller won't work for me:

JS:

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.visible = true;
    $scope.toggle = function() { $scope.visible = !$scope.visible; };
};
```

Html:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="scripts/vendor/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/controllers/app.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app>
    <div ng-controller="MyCtrl"> <button ng-click="toggle()">Toggle</button> 
        <p ng-show="visible">Hello World!</p> 
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Error:

```
[ng:areq] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.0-rc.4/ng/areq?p0=MyCtrl&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20undefined
```

Angular isn't happy with the controller, wonder if I'm using it right or the book is out of date? On Angular website I saw samples of much more sophisticated controller's declaration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From a version on (certainly on 1.3.0-x), Angular requires you to explicitly allow controllers to be declared as global functions. See [the docs for the $controllerProvider](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$controllerProvider).

> ### allowGlobals();
>
> If called, allows $controller to find controller constructors on window

So, your solution is:

```
angular.module("...", []).config(["$controllerProvider", function($controllerProvider) {
    $controllerProvider.allowGlobals();
}]);
```

The above module *has* to be called, so it is either your main module or your main module should depend on it.

Comment: That was it. The books is written for the prev version of angular.

Comment: For fast-changing things like Angular, books get outdated really quickly!

Answer (score 2):

You missed few thing please see code snippet below

```js
var app=angular.module('app', [])

app.controller('MyCtrl',MyCtrl);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.visible = true;
    $scope.toggle = function() { $scope.visible = !$scope.visible; };
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<html>
<head>
    <script src="scripts/vendor/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/controllers/app.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="MyCtrl"> <button ng-click="toggle()">Toggle</button> 
        <p ng-show="visible">Hello World!</p> 
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Glueing the controllers and the template is a bit tricky in the beginning. @sss showes how it's done.
To just check that every thing else is sane you can put the script into you html page. Note, this is just for debugging and I realize this is not what you want. Just a tip for beginners:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0-beta.8/angular.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app>

<script>
    function MyCtrl($scope) {
        $scope.visible = true;
        $scope.toggle = function() { $scope.visible = !$scope.visible; };
    };
</script>

<div ng-controller="MyCtrl"> <button ng-click="toggle()">Toggle</button>
    <p ng-show="visible">Hello World!</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

this is the simplest example from [angular docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller)

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('GreetingController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.greeting = 'Hola!';
}]);
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <script src="scripts/vendor/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/controllers/app.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp">
<div ng-controller="GreetingController">
{{ greeting }}
</div>
</body>
```

you missed the `var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);` and `<body ng-app="myapp">`, i recommend you to read carefully the [angular docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller).